# get lastInsertId using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am unable to get the lastInserId using PDO in php

```
$conn = new Db();
$query = "INSERT INTO orders SET
    order_timestamp= :orderTimestamp ,
    customer_id= :customerId";                      
$stmt = $conn->dbConnect()->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':orderTimestamp', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':customerId', $_SESSION["customerId"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$orderId = $conn->lastInsertId();
return $orderId;
```

Below is the code used for DB Connection

```
public function dbConnect(){
try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }   
    return $conn;
}
```

I am getting an error as mentioned below.

> Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   H:\xampp\htdocs\php\tuf4\hunger\includes\classes\class.hunger.php on
>   line 31
>
> Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Db::lastInsertId() in
>   H:\xampp\htdocs\php\tuf4\hunger\includes\classes\class.hunger.php on
>   line 34

Comment: What does "unable" mean?  What *do* you get?  What value?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Does your table have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` row?

Comment: yeah. i am having auto increment.

Comment: Does the code written works? I mean in syntax point of view

Comment: Why are you using `return $orderId;` are you inside a function or what ?

Comment: I think that question is for you to answer?  Does it?  Do you see errors?

Comment: No the errors are being resolved as directed by @Niet.
But, the value returned is **"0"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bindParam` expects a variable, to be passed by reference. `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` is clearly not a variable ;)

Try `bindValue` instead.

Using the correct function will stop the domino effect of errors, and allow you to get the `lastInsertId` you are seeking.

EDIT: On further review, you are trying to call `lastInsertId` on your `Db` wrapper class, *not* on the `PDO` object. Try:

```
$pdo = $conn->dbConnect();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
// ...
$orderId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Ok. That warning is being resolved. What about the fatal error thing?

Comment: @CkMaurya I literally just edited at the same time you asked that XD See edit.

Comment: I did that @Niet. The errors are resolved but, the value returned is always zero

Comment: You can check the DB record @ http://prntscr.com/3hdb2c, but still the output thrown is "0"

Comment: Does it requires to use $db->beginTransaction(); and $db->commit();

Comment: ty @Niet for the partial solution ;)